# SharePoint REST Service Create List Item Error The required version of WcfDataServices is missing.

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to insert an item to a list (just a basic custom list with the title column) using the SharePoint Web Services.  This is the code I am using

```
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
        return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1) + "ListItem";
    }


        var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(lisNameTitle);
        var item = {
            '__metadata': { 'type': itemType },
            'Title': 'another item check if works'
        };
        var jsonItem = JSON.stringify(item);
        alert(jsonItem);

        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: reportDownloadSubmitDataUrl,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: jsonItem,
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            }
        })
```

when I execute this code, on the SharePoint side logs I get the following errors

**"The required version of WcfDataServices is missing. Please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=321931 for more information." String**

**WcfDataServices 5.6 is missing.**

I have SharePoint 2013 Service Pack 1 installed on my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem was due to the $http( method in Angularjs.  When I used directly jquery to post the result ($.ajax) it worked fine.